# Py2App can't find usable tk.tcl

Tags: python, tkinter, py2app

I'm trying to create an OS X Python 3 app with py2app using a Tkinter GUI. I have upgraded Python on my machine to v3.6.0 and installed the correct version of ActiveTcl (v8.5.18.0). I can develop and run the app fine, I can create an alias build and it runs fine but when I create and try to run a standalone version, I get an error saying that `tk.tcl` can not be found.

I have scoured the internet and have found older references to this online with other missing files but I can not find any solution which fixes my problem. I know where my tk.tcl file is, but I don't know how to tell it where to look for it, and I don't know why it's in a non-standard place anyway.

Can anyone help me with this?

Full error message below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Ste/Documents/Programming/rf-library/src/test/dist/test.app/Contents/Resources/__boot__.py", line 81, in <module>
    _run()
  File "/Users/Ste/Documents/Programming/rf-library/src/test/dist/test.app/Contents/Resources/__boot__.py", line 66, in _run
    exec(compile(source, path, 'exec'), globals(), globals())
  File "/Users/Ste/Documents/Programming/rf-library/src/test/dist/test.app/Contents/Resources/test.py", line 10, in <module>
    gui = tk.Tk()
  File "tkinter/__init__.pyc", line 2017, in __init__
_tkinter.TclError: Can't find a usable tk.tcl in the following directories: 

/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Versions/8.5/Resources/Scripts/tk8.5
/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Versions/8.5/Resources/Scripts/tk8.5/Resources/Scripts
/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Versions/8.5/Resources/tk8.5
/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Versions/8.5/Resources/tk8.5/Resources/Scripts
/Users/Ste/Documents/Programming/rf-library/src/test/dist/test.app/Contents/lib/tk8.5
/Users/Ste/Documents/Programming/rf-library/src/test/dist/test.app/Contents/lib/tk8.5/Resources/Scripts
~/Library/Tcl/tk8.5 ~/Library/Tcl/tk8.5/Resources/Scripts /Library/Tcl/tk8.5
/Library/Tcl/tk8.5/Resources/Scripts
/System/Library/Tcl/tk8.5
/System/Library/Tcl/tk8.5/Resources/Scripts
~/Library/Frameworks/tk8.5
~/Library/Frameworks/tk8.5/Resources/Scripts
/Library/Frameworks/tk8.5
/Library/Frameworks/tk8.5/Resources/Scripts
/System/Library/Frameworks/tk8.5
/System/Library/Frameworks/tk8.5/Resources/Scripts
/Users/Ste/Documents/Programming/rf-library/src/test/dist/test.app/lib/tk8.5
/Users/Ste/Documents/Programming/rf-library/src/test/dist/test.app/Contents/library



This probably means that tk wasn't installed properly.

called Tcl_CreateHashEntry on deleted table
Abort trap: 6
```

Comment: Have you tried using Pyinstaller (from git)? That mostly packages apps correctly

Comment: I don't believe it supports Python 3.6 yet.

Comment: I have used it with 3.6 using the develop branch `pip install https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/tarball/develop` or clone from their git

Comment: Thanks. I have got it working but it required a bit of a workaround. I still wonder why my original problem exists though.

Answer (score -1):

What version of py2app are you using? I had the same issue, but I was able to resolve it by downgrading to `py2app 0.11`. I am using `Python 3.5.2` (the one distributed here https://www.python.org/download/releases/3.5.2/), and `ActiveTcl 8.5.18.0` (https://www.activestate.com/activetcl/downloads). It works like a charm.

If you use pip, simply do the following in Terminal:

```
$ pip3 uninstall py2app
$ pip3 install py2app==0.11
```

Just FYI, I recently upgraded my Python version and a number of things (including `py2app`). I was under the impression that Python was the culprit. So I tried Python 3.7.0, 3.6.6, and 3.5.4. All this time I was using `py2app 0.12`, without thinking that the problem could be py2app. I also un-installed and re-installed ActiveTcl 8.5.18 multiple times, and I can confirm that was not the issue.